# programmatically convert an x509 certificate into human readable format using openssl api

Tags: c, openssl, x509

In my C based openssl client I am able to make a an ssl connection to a ssl server, and retrieve the ssl certificates presented by the server using

```
X509* cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate( SSL *ssl);
```

Now I want to convert the contents of this X509 certificate in human readable form.
Yes I could have simply displayed on console using:

```
X509_print(stdout,cert);
```

but I don't want to print it just like that. I want to capture the cert contents into some char buffer, so that I may process it further, before I display it the way I choose to.

Googled as much as I could, remained clueless.

Any hacks around who can help me with that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have X.509 cert, you can use various X509 functions such X509_get_version, X509_get_notBefore, X509_get_notAfter, X509_get_subject_name etc. You can look x509.h [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-32/src/crypto/x509/x509.h).

In some cases, like X509_get_subject_name, you will X509_NAME. On X509_NAME, you can use X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID to extract fields such as Common name (by using NID_commonName), Organization etc.

It depends on all what information you want to display. There is no hack. It is just programming. If you need more information, I can post code example also. But I believe that this must be sufficient to get started.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as "human-readable format of X.509 certificate", that's why you can find nothing. Each software extracts different information and shows it differently. As pointed in the other answer, you can extract data by calling various functions and then print it. Or you can direct output of X509_print to handle other than stdout to grab what OpenSSL produces.

Comment: @Eugine yes, I know about X509_print. But I am trying to capture the output in memory, without performing the file I/O

Comment: @mdk you can direct output to other handle, can't you? And this handle doesn't necessarily need to be file handle, right?

Answer (score 0):

`X509_print` is supposed to take a `BIO` first argument. `X509_print_fp` accepts a `FILE*` like `stdout`.

Print it to a memory bio using `X509_print` (bio flavor), then extract the content using `BIO_get_mem_data`.